p:graphicImage with @requestscoped bean phaseId null
I try load image from a stream with @RequestScoped bean. I use JSF and JavaEE7 with Primefaces 7.0 and Wildfly 9.
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:outputStylesheet name="primeicons/primeicons.css"
        library="primefaces" />
    <h:form>
        <p:scrollPanel>
            <ui:repeat value="${u.fileInfos}" var="image"
                id="manuelSwitcherImages">
                <p:link href="${request.contextPath}/admin/single-fileInfo.xhtml">
                    <f:param name="fileName" value="${image.uniqueFileName}"/>
                    <p:graphicImage value="${imageView.image}" width="500" id="image"
                        rendered="${!image.uniqueFileName.isEmpty()}">
                        <f:param name="fileName" value="${image.uniqueFileName}" />
                    </p:graphicImage>
                </p:link>
            </ui:repeat>
        </p:scrollPanel>
    </h:form>
</ui:composition>

And the backing bean:
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class ImageView implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1067751029307336424L;

    @Inject
    private AppProperties appProperties;

    private DefaultStreamedContent image;
    
    public ImageView() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void setStream() {
        image = new DefaultStreamedContent();
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        Map<String, String> map = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
        String fileName = map.get("fileName");
        System.out.println("PhaseId:" + context.getCurrentPhaseId() + " fileName:"+fileName);
        if (context.getCurrentPhaseId() != PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE) {
            if (fileName != null && !fileName.isEmpty()) {
                image.setContentType("image/jpeg");
                FileInputStream fis;
                try {
                    fis = new FileInputStream(
                            new File(appProperties.getDocinfoRootPath() + File.separatorChar + fileName));
                    image.setStream(fis);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    public DefaultStreamedContent getImage() {
        return image;
    }

}

When I load the page, the following logged to console:
09:48:58,562 INFO  [stdout] (default task-48) PhaseId:RENDER_RESPONSE 6 fileName:null
09:49:02,331 INFO  [stdout] (default task-49) PhaseId:null fileName:IMG_20240801_103857_3362857899511577984.jpg

when I click the link to show Image (or load request: http://localhost:8080/forras-admin/admin/single-fileInfo.xhtml?fileName=IMG_20240801_103857_3362857899511577984.jpg) in a single view the log is following:
10:03:00,553 INFO  [stdout] (default task-114) PhaseId:RENDER_RESPONSE 6 fileName:IMG_20240801_103857_3362857899511577984.jpg

10:03:00,764 INFO  [stdout] (default task-115) PhaseId:null fileName:null

The single view looks like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:dp="http://integrity.hu/dynap"
    template="/WEB-INF/templates/default.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form>
            <p:graphicImage value="${imageView.image}" id="singleimage" />
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>

Why PhaseId is null and what can I do with different file content in RENDER_RESPONSE? And why image is not visible in single view?
Thans a lot for suggestions.

I would really suggest you to use DefaultStreamedContent like in our docs, you dont need any PhaseId check then, its all done and the stream lambda is only called when its really required

The following code is working for me in the single view:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:dp="http://integrity.hu/dynap"
    template="/WEB-INF/templates/default.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form>
            <p:scrollPanel style="width:100%;height:500px;">
                <p:graphicImage value="${imageView.image}" id="singleimage">
                    <f:param name="fileName"
                        value="#{request.getParameter('fileName')}" />
                </p:graphicImage>
            </p:scrollPanel>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>

